# C++ Array Looping Issue

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to create an array of numerical values then count the elements in a `for` loop while getting the array values.

```
if (ShowTalkingPlayers)
{
    memset(TALKING, 0, sizeof(TALKING));
    char *Talker;

    for (int i = 0; i < PLAYER::GET_NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS(); i++)
    {
        if (NETWORK::NETWORK_PLAYER_HAS_HEADSET(i))
        {
            Talker = PLAYER::GET_PLAYER_NAME(i);
            if (NETWORK::NETWORK_IS_PLAYER_TALKING(i)) snprintf(TALKING, sizeof(TALKING), "Mic: ~g~%s", Talker);
            else snprintf(TALKING, sizeof(TALKING), "Mic: ~b~%s", Talker);

            Do_ShowTalkingPlayers(TALKING, i);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a working code the problem is ... It creates space between the players name since it's looping through all 18 players rather than just the players that have a headset. I was thinking doing a for loop before this so i can gather the user id's that have a headset in an array then loop through the array data and display talking players.

DO_SHOWTALKINGPLAYERS is simply the hud natives which play no role in setting up the players with a headset.

Comment: Post real code please. Ideally a [MCVE] that exactly reproduces your problem.

Comment: I edited the question sir.

Answer (score 0):

The `sizeof` operator doesn't do what you expect it to do with raw pointer variables. It will give you the size of the pointer variable (4 or 8 depending on your CPU target architecture), but not of the memory allocated behind.

So

```
 char array[42];
```

will decay to a pointer when called with a function like

```
 void take_array(char* array) {
 }
```

and sizeof within will yield the pointer variable size.

While

```
 void take_array(char array[42]) {
 }
```

would keep that information for being deduced by `sizeof()`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the desired results using a custom Foreach loop posted by someone on this site. Thank you guys who down voted my question.

```
#define foreach(item, array) \
for(int keep = 1, \
        count = 0,\
        size = sizeof (array) / sizeof *(array); \
    keep && count != size; \
    keep = !keep, count++) \
  for(item = (array) + count; keep; keep = !keep)
```

I was wanting to count the data in an array and display them in a loop, so i am posting this for anyone else who wishes to do the same and cannot find the answer.